# How can I tell if a Delphi control is currently visible?

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, visible, paint

I need a way to for a custom control (descended from TCustomControl) to tell if it is currently visible.  I'm not talking about the .Visible property; I mean whether or not it's actually being displayed on-screen at the moment.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean whether or not it is covered by another window?

Comment: I mean whether or not it's getting drawn to the screen. Being covered could be one reason.  Another could be if it's been placed on a form that's been created but not shown yet.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A few years back I had the same kind of problem for a Form: I was looking for a way to determine if a Form is actually visible (even only partially) to the user.
In particular when it was supposed to be visible and Showing was True but the window was actually entirely behind another one.
Here's the code, it could be adapted for a WinControl...

```
{----------------------------------------------------------}
function IsMyFormCovered(const MyForm: TForm): Boolean;
var
   MyRect: TRect;
   MyRgn, TempRgn: HRGN;
   RType: Integer;
   hw: HWND;
begin
  MyRect := MyForm.BoundsRect;            // screen coordinates
  MyRgn := CreateRectRgnIndirect(MyRect); // MyForm not overlapped region
  hw := GetTopWindow(0);                  // currently examined topwindow
  RType := SIMPLEREGION;                  // MyRgn type

// From topmost window downto MyForm, build the not overlapped portion of MyForm
  while (hw<>0) and (hw <> MyForm.handle) and (RType <> NULLREGION) do
  begin
    // nothing to do if hidden window
    if IsWindowVisible(hw) then
    begin
      GetWindowRect(hw, MyRect);
      TempRgn := CreateRectRgnIndirect(MyRect);// currently examined window region
      RType := CombineRgn(MyRgn, MyRgn, TempRgn, RGN_DIFF); // diff intersect
      DeleteObject( TempRgn );
    end; {if}
    if RType <> NULLREGION then // there's a remaining portion
      hw := GetNextWindow(hw, GW_HWNDNEXT);
  end; {while}

  DeleteObject(MyRgn);
  Result := RType = NULLREGION;
end;

function IsMyFormVisible(const MyForm : TForm): Boolean;
begin
  Result:= MyForm.visible and
           isWindowVisible(MyForm.Handle) and
           not IsMyFormCovered(MyForm);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! That's precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: You are a hero.

Comment: This code has a problem. If the form is moved beyond the boundaries of the screen, the result is always False. Even if the form is partially in the screen (and covered).

Answer (score 2):

Could you attach code to the OnPaint event?  This is called very often and I think is only called when the control is actually going to be painted (eg is visible in the way you mean).

Comment: I'd go with this as a best indicator. You can never be sure because in Vista all apps draw to an off-screen bitmap which is then composed in the graphics card with the overlays etc.

Comment: But presumably its still only drawn off screen if it is going to be shown onscreen at the moment?

Comment: I don't think it's safe to assume that WM_PAINT will only come when those pixels are about to hit the screen.  With Desktop Composition (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969540%28VS.85%29.aspx), Windows keeps a cache of drawn windows for effects like Windows Flip (http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/features/flip-3d.aspx) that may require *all* windows at once.  Because of this, I'd expect that there might be some background cache-refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

Francesca's accepted answer works for most cases. However, it doesn't work if the form is moved beyond the boundaries of the screen.

Here is the better answer:

```
function IsMyFormCovered(const MyForm: TForm): Boolean;
var
  RectForm, RectForeground: TRect;
  hWndForeground: HWND;
begin
  GetWindowRect(MyForm.Handle, RectForm);
  hWndForeground := GetForegroundWindow;
  if (hWndForeground <> MyForm.Handle) and (hWndForeground <> 0) then
  begin
    GetWindowRect(hWndForeground, RectForeground);
    if (RectForm.Left < RectForeground.Right) and
       (RectForm.Right > RectForeground.Left) and
       (RectForm.Top < RectForeground.Bottom) and
       (RectForm.Bottom > RectForeground.Top) then
      Result := True
    else
      Result := False;
  end else
    Result := False;
end;
```